# Anyone can recommend book for practice inequalities proof for beginner?

Tags: inequality

I just read real analysis,and found It deal with inequality a lot.Some problem is very difficult for me. I try to find book about proving inequality for practice ,but I can find only problem book from olympiad,putnum or very difficult problem for me.Anyone can help me to find it?

Comment: Try Steele's *The Cauchy–Schwarz Master Class*: https://www.amazon.com/Cauchy-Schwarz-Master-Class-Introduction-Mathematical/dp/052154677X

Answer (score 1):

[This link](http://www.mit.edu/~pengshi/math149/inequalities.pdf) contains a tutorial on inequalities from Duke University. They've explained the basics of inequalities and also proved a few theorems nicely.
Hope it helps!